# Is $\mathbf{Rel}$ pre-additive?

Tags: category-theory, additive-categories

I first fix some notation: 
the objects are given by Ob **Rel** = Ob **Set**. The morphisms are given by $\hom(A,B)= \mathcal{P}(A \times B)$. Let $R \colon A \to B$ and $S \colon B \to C$. Composition is given by $(a,c) \in S \circ R \iff \exists b ~ \text{s.t.} ~ (a,b) \in R ~ \text{and} ~ (b,c) \in S$.

This category, correct me if I am wrong, is semi-additive with both product and coproduct given by disjoint union.

I wish to know if it is additive. Can one enrich the hom-sets with a group structure bilinear with respect to composition? I propose the following group structure:

$R+S := (R \cup S) - (R \cap S)$

Comment: I don't believe so. Composition preserves $\cup$ but not $\cap$.

Comment: Yep, I found a counter-example already in $\mathrm{End}(\{1,2\})$. Does this mean no group structure exists that makes $\mathrm{Rel}$ pre-additive though?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can think about morphisms in $\text{Rel}$ as being matrices over a particular [semiring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiring), namely the **truth semiring** $\{ 0, 1 \}$. This is the semiring of subsets of a one-element set, with addition given by union (not symmetric difference!) and multiplication given by intersection. Equivalently, it's the semiring $\text{End}(1)$ in $\text{Rel}$.

This semiring is manifestly not a ring, since its addition operation is not cancellative, so there's no reason to expect additivity. The same reasoning applies to categories of matrices over more general semirings.

Answer (score 6):

Given a category $\mathcal{C}$ with a zero object and a biproduct (i.e. coproduct canonically isomorphic to product), there is (up to isomorphism) at most one additive structure on $\mathcal{C}$. Indeed, given $f, g : X \to Y$, we must have:
$$f + g = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} f & 0 \\ 0 & g \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} = \nabla \circ (f \oplus g) \circ \Delta$$
In particular, for $\mathbf{Rel}$, this gives $\cup$ as the binary operation on hom-sets. This is not cancellative, so there is no way of making $\mathbf{Rel}$ into an additive category.

Comment: Do you have a good reference for this statement? I don't know what the triangle symbols represent, and I would like to look into it in more detail.

Comment: $\Delta : X \to X \times X$ is the diagonal morphism, and $\nabla : X \amalg X \to X$ is the codiagonal morphism.

Comment: @Aaron: the only place I know where this material is written up is http://qchu.wordpress.com/2012/09/14/a-meditation-on-semiadditive-categories/ (but I am sure it exists in a real book somewhere). The uniqueness statement follows from the corollary which states that a functor between semiadditive categories is enriched iff it preserves biproducts.